# How to count the comparisons made in Quick Sort

Tags: python, quicksort

So I have a fully written and working code for quick sort but instead of returning the sorted list, I am trying to have it return the number of comparisons. I am not sure where I should put the counter to count the number of comparisons made. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```py
def quickSort(alist):
   quickSortHelper(alist,0,len(alist)-1)

def quickSortHelper(alist,first,last):
   if first<last:

       splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)

       quickSortHelper(alist,first,splitpoint-1)
       quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)


def partition(alist,first,last):
   pivotvalue = alist[first]

   leftmark = first+1
   rightmark = last

   done = False
   while not done:

       while leftmark <= rightmark and alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
           leftmark = leftmark + 1

       while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and rightmark >= leftmark:
           rightmark = rightmark -1

       if rightmark < leftmark:
           done = True
       else:
           temp = alist[leftmark]
           alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
           alist[rightmark] = temp

   temp = alist[first]
   alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
   alist[rightmark] = temp


   return rightmark   #returns the sorted list
```

Comment: since quicksort is essentially recursively partitioning an array, the only way I can define comparisons would be the while loops?

Answer (score 1):

Those two loops are the only places where you actually compare values from the array:

```
       while leftmark <= rightmark and alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
           leftmark = leftmark + 1

       while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and rightmark >= leftmark:
           rightmark = rightmark -1
```

so you should add `counter += 1` inside both loops. Remember to initialize the counter to 0 and to declare it as global.

BTW, `leftmark = leftmark + 1` can be written as `leftmark += 1`
and this part:

```
           temp = alist[leftmark]
           alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
           alist[rightmark] = temp
```

doesn't require a temporary variable:

```
           alist[rightmark],alist[leftmark] = alist[leftmark],alist[rightmark]
```